# How can I remove ~$ files using git bash (on windows)

Tags: windows, git-bash

I don't see the file in explored, even with the "show hidden objects" setting.
On the other hand git shows it as untracked files and I found no way to remove it.

Any ideas?

```
git status
On branch devSQC
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/devSQC'.

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        pathto/~$crazy file.xlsx

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)


ls pathto/
'~$crazy file.xlsx'

git rm -f 'pathto/~$crazy file.xlsx'
fatal: pathspec 'pathto/~$crazy file.xlsx' did not match any files
```

I know those are windows files for recovery, but windows does not allow to do anything either and I hope git bash is better ;-)
See e.g. [here](https://www.easeus.com/file-recovery/fix-folder-not-showing-files.html) but I hope, I don't need to install additional tools...

Comment: It's *untracked*, which means that there is no copy in Git's index (aka staging area). It's probably not in any existing commit either. So Git literally *can't* remove it from Git, as it does not exist *in* Git. You probably want to list these patterns in an exclusion file (e.g., your global `.gitignore`) so that Git doesn't complain about them existing but being untracked, as it's doing now.

Comment: @torek Sorry, you are right, I just refer to the terminal (git bash). It is of course not a git feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized, it is simple to remove those files within bash (of course, it has nothing to do with git...)

```
cd path2/
rm -f '~$FHS_Noten STAT_FS2019_TZ17_Noten_Vorlage.xlsx'
```

`git-rm` does not work because it

> Remove files from the working tree and from the index

so it is not a function to delete files.